# Can this be described as “there are three sets”?

Tags: grammatical-number

[image]

Can this be described as “there are three sets”?

1. Set A
2. Set B
3. Set AnB (intersection of A and B)

Comment: Yes. (A and B) is a set, and is also a subset of both A and B. (A or B) is floating around in there somewhere, too.

Comment: Plus anything else you can define as a set. They aren't "there", in the sense of being on the paper. They exist in the mind of the definer, who tries to represent the sets he is thinking of by a paper diagram. So, it's sort of backwards to look at the paper and ask how many sets there are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually more than three sets visible in your diagram. The union is another, there are the two difference sets A-B and B-A and there is the (disjoint) union of the difference sets. There are only three labelled sets though.

I would normally use something like "the diagram shows two sets A and B with non-empty intersection".

Comment: I think there are also set A-B and set B-A.

Comment: (Set A and not set B) is a distinct set, as is (Set B and not Set A)